# How to do addition of webElement? e.getText() gives output in string format and I want to do addition of this output numbers

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> myElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]"));
            for(WebElement e : myElements) {
            System.out.println(e.getText());                        
             }
```

Output=

```
150
20
58
16
28
1
1
246
22
229
199
7
18
35
350
146
106
786
3
2
1
2
46
11
204
193
1
386
1
445
33
261
195
```

Comment: If you are looking for Integers addition then convert the output string  into Integer using `int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the output to an array list and convert into integer array, then calculate entire int array,

```
ArrayList<String> output_webelement = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement e : myElements) {
    output_webelement.add(e.getText())
    System.out.println(e.getText());
}

int[] number_string = new int[output_webelement.size()];
for(int i = 0;i < output_webelement.size();i++)
{
   number_string[i] = Integer.parseInt(output_webelement[i]);
}

int total_sum = IntStream.of(number_string).sum();
System.out.println("Total sum: " + total_sum);
```